# Difference between Embed, Embed Advanced or Dynamic Map

Tags: google-maps

I'm using Google Maps Javascript API to add maps to a site. Now when Google are making changes to their prices I am unsure what my limit is. This [site](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/sheet/) lists the prices but how do I know if I am using the Embed, Embed Advanced or Dynamic Map?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can share information obtained from the Google Maps Platform technical support. Billing SKUs can be found in their [Pricing Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/billing-and-pricing/pricing)

Now, referring to your question,

- **Embed** SKU refers to a basic [Maps Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide) request that uses map or a map with a marker (not including the Directions mode, Street View mode, or Search mode). These requests are free of charge.
- **Embed Advanced** SKU refers to an advanced [Maps Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide) request that uses the Directions mode, Street View mode, or Search mode. These requests are also free of charge. User interactions with the map, such as panning, zooming, or switching map layers, do not generate additional map loads. Embed Advanced were charged before, but they changed this with their recent update. For it currently says in their pricing docs that,

> *"All Maps Embed API requests are available at no charge with unlimited usage."*

- **Dynamic Map** SKU refers to a web page or application that displays a map using the [Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial). A map is created with the `google.maps.Map()` class. Any user interactions with the map, such as panning, zooming, or switching map layers, do not generate additional map loads. The creation of a Street View panorama is no longer charged as a map load, it is charged as a “Dynamic Street View”.

I hope my answer clarifies your doubts.

Comment: Thank you. So if we switch over to using embeded maps we can still zoom and pan without it costing anything? That's how I interpret your answer and also what I have gather from Google documentation

Comment: Correct, if you integrate Google Maps Embed API in basic mode (without directions, street view or search) it will be free of charge.