# Two questions about google maps embedded api

Tags: html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have two questions about the google maps embedded api.

1.) What does the option "Map loads per 100 seconds per user" exactly do? Does it limit the requests per api key per second or does it limit the requests per client user (ip?)

2.) Google will change its pricing in june. Can I still use the embed api for free if I embed it likes this:

< iframe width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=YOUR_API_KEY &q=Space+Needle,Seattle+WA&zoom=17&maptype=roadmap&language=de" allowfullscreen

Answer (score 3):

The "Map loads per 100 seconds per user" sets a quota on per client user (IP address). There is no option to set quota on per API key basis.

The sample iframe that you put in the question uses Embed API in place mode. If you don't use Directions mode, Street View mode, or Search mode it is considered as basic Embed API request and according to the price sheet it is free of charge.

https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/sheet/

> #### Embed API
>
> Embed with Dynamic Maps or a map with a marker, will continue to be free with unlimited usage. Embed API requests using Directions mode, Street View mode, or Search mode will now be billed. See the pricing table for details.

source: https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/user-guide/pricing-changes/#embed-api

Another question that might be useful for you:

[Difference between Embed, Embed Advanced or Dynamic Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50465251/difference-between-embed-embed-advanced-or-dynamic-map)

I hope this clarifies your doubts!